# I want to assign public ip to my openvpn access server clients

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn

I want to assign public ip to my openvpn access server clients not private ip as i can use this public ip to access my localhosts in each machine Am already owned my cloud openvpn access server on digitalocean

Comment: You can use public networks anywhere you use private networks, provided you properly own them, and in this case your public network should be routed towards your VPN server. To have a detailed useful answer, please describe more thoroughly what problem you have with that. At least, how big is your public network address block (e.g. subnet mask), the kind of VPN configuration (routed/bridged) and so on.

Comment: i don't have public network 
i want help to have this public network IPs 
and assign this to my openvpn access server 
to be able call any of my local hosts in my laptops from outside my network

i'm using digitalocean for openvpn cloud access server
so if i can use same digital ocean to get this public ips

Comment: You need to ask DigitalOcean if they can provide you with public IP addresses that can be used with your VPS.